# Re-assignment of variable doesn't work

Tags: objective-c

I have a puzzling problem -- it seems like it should be so easy to do but somehow it is not working.  I have an object called Player.  The Manager class has four instances of Player:

```
@interface Manager
{
    Player *p1, *p2, *mCurrentPlayer, *mCurrentOpponent;  
}
// @property...
```

The Manager object has initPlayers and swapPlayers methods.

```
-(void) initPlayers {  // this works fine
    self.p1 = [[Player alloc] init];
    self.p2 = [[Player alloc] init];
    self.mCurrentPlayer = self.p1;
    self.mCurrentOpponent = self.p2;
}

-(void) swapPlayers {  // this swapping of pointer doesn't work
    self.mCurrentPlayer = self.p2;
    self.mCurrentOpponent = self.p1;

    // When I look at the pointer in debugger, self.mCurrentPlayer is still self.p1.  :-(

    // I even tried first setting them to nil, 
    // or first releasing them (with an extra retain on assignment) to no avail
}
```

What am I missing?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you also post the @property code from your interface?

Comment: @property(nonatomic, retain) Player *p1, *p1, *mCurrentPlayer, *mCurrentOpponent;

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing how your accessors are set up, it will be difficult to troubleshoot the code as-is. That being said, here is how your accessors and code *should* be set up:

> **Manager.h**

```
@interface Manager 
{
    Player *p1, *p2, *mCurrentPlayer, *mCurrentOpponent;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) Player *p1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Player *p2;
@property (nonatomic, assign) Player *mCurrentPlayer;
@property (nonatomic, assign) Player *mCurrentOpponent;
@end
```

> **Manager.m**

```
-(void) initPlayers {
    self.p1 = [[[Player alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.p2 = [[[Player alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.mCurrentPlayer = self.p1;
    self.mCurrentOpponent = self.p2;
}

-(void) swapPlayers {
    Player * temp = self.mCurrentPlayer;
    self.mCurrentPlayer = self.mCurrentOpponent;
    self.mCurrentOpponent = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was somewhere unrelated in the code and I misread the symptoms of the problem!  But just for the sake of discussion, why is it necessary to have @property on multiple lines, and to use a temp variable to swap the players (as per e.James answer)?

Comment: You should post this comment as a comment on e.James answer.  In any case, your code doesn't swap players;  it'll always make p2 the current player and p1 the current opponent.

Comment: @twinkle: I'm not sure about combining the `@property` declarations onto one line. I've never done it that way, but it might work.

Comment: Combined declarations work fine though you obviously can't have both assign and retain on the same line. :)